# Keep getting invalid credentials when login node.js + Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am fairly new to node.js and trying to get my login credentials from the database, I can successfully get login credentials from the database but when I call it from my server.js file, I keep getting Invalid credentials even though they are the right credentials. I will appreciate it if fresh eyes could look into this and point out what I am doing wrong. Using Postgres DB

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const loginCredentials = {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }

    if (loginCredentials.email === '' && loginCredentials.password === '') {
      return res.status(500).send('Email and Password required')
    }
    if (loginCredentials.email === '' || loginCredentials.password === '') {
      return res.status(500).send('Email and Password required')
    }
    if (loginCredentials.email && loginCredentials.password ) {
      // getting credentials from db.login
      const result = await db.login(loginCredentials.email, loginCredentials.password)
      console.log('* ' + result)
      if (result) {
        res.status(200).send("Success")
      } else {
        res.status(401).send("Invalid Credentials")
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
```

### and here is my db.login method

```
async function login(email, password) {
  console.debug("login db")
  const query = `SELECT *
                 FROM users
                 WHERE email = $1`
  const client = await pool.connect()
  try {
    await client.query(query, [email], async function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      }
      console.debug('hash: ' + result.rows[0].hash)
      console.debug('pass: ' + password)

      if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        const user = result.rows[0]
        //role = user.role
        const validPassword =  bcrypt.compare(password, user.hash)
        if (!validPassword){
          console.log('Invalid Credentials')
          return 'Invalid Credentials'
        }else {
          console.debug('success')
          return user
        }
      } else {
        return 'No user in the DB'
      }
    
    })
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not `await`ing the `compare` method's result, so `validPassword` will always be an unresolved `Promise`, not the result.

Adding await should fix it:

```js
const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.hash)
```

EDIT: I see you check with `if (!validPassword)`, which is never "truthy" if `validPassword` is a `Promise`. You might want to check what version of bcrypt you are using - does `compare` return a Promise, or is this maybe an old version that uses a callback signature only. In that case you should either update your bcrypt dependency, or use the callback method instead: `compare(password, user.hash, function(err, validPassword) { /* check validPassword here */ })`.

You might also want to check your flow, you return the user from the `client.query` callback, but you are also `await`ing it, but not storing or returning its return value. I have no experience with the Postgres API, but it looks like you are mixing Promises (with async/await) and callbacks. In my experience it's always one or the other - you either use the callback flow, or returned Promise flow. If `client.query` returns a Promise, it will probably resolve with the results you are now handling with the callback.

Try rewriting it this way:

```js
async function login(email, password) {
  console.debug("login db")
  const query = `SELECT *
                 FROM users
                 WHERE email = $1`
  const client = await pool.connect()
  try {
    const result = await client.query(query, [email])

    console.debug('hash: ' + result.rows[0].hash)
    console.debug('pass: ' + password)

    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
      const user = result.rows[0]
      //role = user.role
      const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.hash)
      if (!validPassword){
        console.log('Invalid Credentials')
        return 'Invalid Credentials'
      }else {
        console.debug('success')
        return user
      }
    } else {
      return 'No user in the DB'
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Another edit: Notice that the code above will now actually return something, either the user row or a string. Previously, your `db.login` method returned a Promise that resolved without a value, always failing your following `if (result)` check because `result` is `undefined`. If you change your `db.login` code to the above, the `if (result)` will now always be true because it is either a string or the user object. You might want to `throw 'Invalid credentials'` and `throw 'No user in the DB'` instead, and wrap the `db.login(..)` call in try / catch:

```js
try {
   const result = await db.login(loginCredentials.email, loginCredentials.password)
   res.status(200).send("Success")
}
catch(err) {
   res.status(401).send("Invalid Credentials")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, that helped me. it was my fault to mix promise and async await